# C program lottery

Tags: c

I have homework with the following instruction:

This program requires the student to write a C program that will generate one year of 3-digit lottery numbers between 000 and 999. When the program begins the user will be asked to buy one year of lottery tickets.  It cost $1.00 for each ticket.   The user will provide his or her favorite number.  Each ticket purchased with have the exact same number that was provided from the user. The program will output the number of times the user’s ticket matched the daily number from the lottery.  Each time the user hits the lottery he or she wins $500.00.
The final output will be the number of times the user hit the lottery during the past year.  The program will calculate and display the amount of money the user has after one-year passes.

I feel like I'm missing something or program not written correctly
Thanks in advance
Here is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int fav_number;
    int i;
    int total_wins = 0;
    printf("Please buy one year of lottery It just costs $1 a day!!!!\n");
    printf("Enter your favourite number\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &fav_number);
    for (i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
        int random_number = (rand() % 1000);
        if (random_number == fav_number) {
            total_wins += 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Total number of wins in the past year = %d \n", total_wins);
    printf("Money he had after one year passes = $%d \n", total_wins * 500-365);
}
```

Comment: You should pay attention to the compiler warnings and fix those issues first. I see no issues otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, Christopher, I fixed the issues. One last question, do you feel like the code solves the problem asked in the assignment.

Comment: Yeah I don't see any problems with it.

Comment: `if (scanf_s("%d", &fav_number) != 1) { /* handle matching failure or manual EOF */ }` You cannot use any user-input function correctly without ***checking the return*** `:)` Tip -- you only need a single `puts(...)` to output the prompt and a single `printf` to output the results.

Comment: I see a huge issue. The lottery is not random at all. Consider calling `srand` at the start of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Everythings looks fine except that you need to include stdio.h as it is needed for scanf and printf functions to execute

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming that you are wondering why your program is not compiling.

This is because you have not included stdio.h as a header. The functions printf (and scanf_s since you are using a Microsoft compiler) are defined in this header. You just need to include it.

In other words, add `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: The program is likely compiling, but they are ignoring the warnings.